# 2020 Toyota Sienna same wheel size as a 2014 Toyota Sienna?

Tags: toyota, wheels, sienna

I'm wanting to buy a 2020 Toyota Sienna Limited (premium) but I want to be sure that it will fit my old snow tires/wheel/rims that I have for my 2014 Toyota Sienna Limited.

btw, the rims I have are:  17 X 7.5 5-112/114 ET40 PL ORIO from TireRack

Does anyone know?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: check the sizes on the 2020 model - may fit or may not... my car can have 16, 17 18 or even 19" as standard so you have check.

Comment: 2020 rim size is 18" P235/55RF18 and my current snow tires are 235/60R17 Michelin Latitude X-Ice Xi2.  I believe I can run 17s on a car with 18s, but wanted to be sure that the bolt pattern and length will work.

Comment: So what are the pcd values for both rims? Will those 17” clear the front brakes?

Comment: Since you purchased the wheels from Tire Rack, you should call them and ask them if they fit the 2020 model.